# Access 2010 SQL - UPDATE query not working

Tags: sql, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I need to create a query for updating a column in a table with values taken from another table and matching a field.

These are the 2 tables:

```
tblMain
  ID     Autonumbering
  Key    Text
  Stat1  Integer

tblStat1 
  ID     Autonumbering
  Key    Text
  Freq   Integer
```

I want to **UPDATE** the `tblMain.Stat1` column with `tblStat1.Freq` value on each record in which `tblMain.Key = tblStat1.Key`.

I tried this syntax (found somewhere as an example)

```
  UPDATE tblMain
  SET tblMain.Stat1 = tblStat1.Freq
  WHERE tblMain.Key = tblStat1.Key;
```

This doesn't work and returns an error on the 2nd row.

After some trials I found that the correct syntax (built with the Access query generator) is this:

```
  UPDATE (tblMaibn INNER JOIN tblStat1 ON tblMain.Key = tblStat1.Key)
  SET tblMain.Stat1 = tblStat1.Freq;
```

In this 2nd syntax, there is no trace of the WHERE condition.
Can someone help me to understand what's wrong with the 1st syntax.
Since I'm building a new table (the join), how can it work on tblMain?
As I said, I found the wrong syntax as an example of UPDATE statement.

Thank you in advance.
Bye, 
Ivano

Comment: A `join` doesn't build a new table.  It describes a particular operation between two tables/subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening in your first query on the 2nd row, is that Access isn't aware of what tblStat1 represents in your query.

The reason your 2nd query is working is because it uses an inner join on the relevant key. In order for SQL to be aware of what record in tblMain relates to which record in tblStat1, you need to use a join.

You can see in the generated code that it is updating your desired table, but joining onto the second table. The where condition is redundant as you're updating every record.

Answer (score 1):

In 1st syntax, you can change:

```
UPDATE tblMain
 SET tblMain.Stat1 = (SELECT Freq
                      FROM tblStat1
                      WHERE tblMain.Key = tblStat1.Key)
```

Comment: Thank you very much to all:-)